# Attempting to pause a campaign in PHP SDK Bing Ads API returning error code "InvalidAccountId"

Tags: php, bing-ads-api

I am using Laravel PHP with the package `"microsoft/bingads": "^13.0"` installed through composer. I wanted to test pause a campaign on one of the active campaign I have in Bing Ads. The error I am getting is invalid AccountId, but I know for sure the AccountId is valid I downloaded a campaigns report.

Below are is my code and the SOAP error:

TestPauseCampaign.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands\Bing;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use App\Services\BingAds;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ServiceClientType;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ServiceClient;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ApiEnvironment;
use Microsoft\BingAds\v13\CampaignManagement\UpdateCampaignsRequest;
use Microsoft\BingAds\V13\CampaignManagement\Campaign;
use Microsoft\BingAds\V13\CampaignManagement\CampaignStatus;
use SoapFault;

class TestPauseCampaign extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'app:test-pause-campaign';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $bing = new BingAds();
        $authorizationData = $bing->getAuthorizationData();
        $serviceClient = (new ServiceClient(ServiceClientType::CampaignManagementVersion13, $authorizationData, ApiEnvironment::Production));

        try {
            $request = new UpdateCampaignsRequest();
            $request->AccountId = 14191111;

            Log::info($request->AccountId);

            $campaign = new Campaign();
            $campaign->Id = '34234234';
            $campaign->Status = CampaignStatus::Paused;

            $request->Campaigns = [$campaign];

            $response = $serviceClient->GetService()->UpdateCampaigns($request);

            Log::info($response);;
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            // Handle SOAP fault

            // Access the fault code
            $faultCode = $e->faultcode;

            // Access the fault string (error message)
            $faultString = $e->getMessage();

            // Access the fault details, if available
            $faultDetails = $e->detail; // This may contain more specific error information

            // Log or display the fault details for debugging
            // You can use var_dump or print_r to view the details
            Log::error(print_r($faultCode, true));
            Log::error(print_r($faultString, true));
            Log::error(print_r($faultDetails, true));

            // Handle the error as needed
            // You can log the details, display an error message, or take other actions
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            //throw $th;
            Log::error($th);
        }

    }
}
```

Error Log

```
[2023-09-25 22:21:10] local.INFO: 14191111  
[2023-09-25 22:21:10] local.ERROR: s:Server  
[2023-09-25 22:21:10] local.ERROR: Invalid client data. Check the SOAP fault details for more information. TrackingId: 604ded6c-ffff-ffff-xxxx-dca58bc456f2.  
[2023-09-25 22:21:10] local.ERROR: stdClass Object
(
    [AdApiFaultDetail] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TrackingId] => 604ded6c-18fa-46df-bf9f-dca58bc456f2
            [Errors] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AdApiError] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Code] => 119
                            [Detail] => 
                            [ErrorCode] => InvalidAccountId
                            [Message] => The account ID is invalid.
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I tested with different AccountIds and Campaigns, none of them works, just the same error.
I even double checked the code that its only related to campaigns.
I expected the campaign to pause with no issues or errors. But I am getting

```
[AdApiError] => stdClass Object
(
  [Code] => 119
  [Detail] => 
  [ErrorCode] => InvalidAccountId
  [Message] => The account ID is invalid.
)
```